# Identify Variables/Function generated from the custom pass?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am programmatically analysing the llvm code. There are some LLVM functions and variables generated from the customised pass written outside the LLVM source code. Is there a programmatically way i could distinguish between the original LLVM source code and LLVM code generated from the customised pass.

Answer (score 1):

If the pass does some distinguishable transformation - yes. For example, if functions created by the pass are named using some convention, or have a specific attribute attached.

Otherwise, you can write your own pass that runs right before the custom one and build a list of functions present in the module. After the custom pass finishes, run this pass again and figure out what functions were added by the custom one.

Comment: I imagine attaching metadata to all the global objects created by the would also be sufficient in this case.